# coredate data not show at tableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have used coredate on the tableView,when I enter the viewController:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("socket login", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext =[self getManagedObjectContext];
    noticListArr=[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] readEvent:@"NotificationEntity" SortDescriptor:nil managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"refreshData.count:%d ",noticListArr.count);
    for(int i=0;i<noticListArr.count;i++){
        NotificationEntity *notificationEntity=[noticListArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.name:%@ ",notificationEntity.name);
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.describeString:%@ ",notificationEntity.describeString);
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.source:%@", notificationEntity.source);
    }     
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView1 reloadData];
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

all logs contains value but when I used

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NotificationViewCell";
     NotificationViewCell *cell = (NotificationViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     NotificationEntity *notificationEntity=(NotificationEntity *)[noticListArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSLog(@"tableViewnoticListArr.count:%d ",noticListArr.count);
     NSLog(@"indexPath.row:%d ",indexPath.row);

     NSLog(@"notificationTable.avatarsmall:%@", notificationEntity.avatarsmall);
     NSLog(@"notificationTable.source:%@", notificationEntity.source);
     NSLog(@"notificationTable.name:%@", notificationEntity.name);
     NSLog(@"notificationTable.describeString:%@ ",notificationEntity.describeString);
 }
```

only

```
 NSLog(@"tableViewnoticListArr.count:%d ",noticListArr.count);
 NSLog(@"indexPath.row:%d ",indexPath.row);
```

gives me correct result but all notificationEntity.name notificationEntity.describeString is null.I don't know why  at the tabelview cell all the values of notificationEntity is null.

Comment: In your tableview, is your `noticListArr` initialized? I'm asking this because I see in the GCD code you assigned `noticListArr`, but not in your tableview.

Comment: noticListArr is my globle var,it frist init from viewdidload,and then have value noticListArr=[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] readEvent:@"NotificationEntity" SortDescriptor:nil managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; it not null.

Comment: noticListArr is the same as frist.frist is have vlaue.but put it at tableView ,noticListArr.counter is correct.but other attr is null

Comment: Hmm...this is really weird. I currently have no logical answer for this. I do see that in your tableview, your `NotificationEntity *notification` is type casted, while it's not typecasted in your GCD. Maybe you can remove the type cast and see what happens.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4006500  i put my code at here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this change,

```
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self getManagedObjectContext];
    self.noticListArr = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] readEvent:@"NotificationEntity" SortDescriptor:nil managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"refreshData.count:%d ",noticListArr.count);
    for(int i=0; i<noticListArr.count; i++){
        NotificationEntity *notificationEntity = [noticListArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.name:%@ ", notificationEntity.name);
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.describeString:%@ ", notificationEntity.describeString);
        NSLog(@"notificationEntity.source:%@", notificationEntity.source);
    }     
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView1 reloadData];
    });
});

dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```